# Cannot create Android project in VS2015 on Windows 7

Tags: android, xamarin, visual-studio-2015

When I create a new Android project on Visual Studio 2015 on Windows 7 (by Xamarin), I run into this error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

*Options->Xamarin->Android Settings* are OK: JDK, Android SDK and NDK locations are correctly checked.

Answer (score 0):

I think u haven't Java drive in your computer. U have to download jdk and install or if u r have jdk (Java) enter in google how to set jdk to windows

Comment: jdk1.8.0_51 is installed. What do you mean when you say set jdk to Windows?

Comment: Some time when u installed Java windows don't know about jdk. E

Comment: Search how to set jdk

Comment: The only issue I found is how to set the JAVA_HOME environment variable but nothing is changed.

Comment: Did u restart computer after set

Comment: Strangely I can create new project using Ware App template but not Blank App template.

Answer (score 0):

Its the Xamarin error don't look after that you complete your code and use debug for the code it will run.

Comment: I cannot debug my code because I cannot create a new Android project.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK Android need jdk 1.7, not 1.8
http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#Requirements